# Koma article class linespacing problems

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing

Now I have badbox warning with this table :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\begin{@twocolumnfalse} 

\begin{abstract}
some text here
\end{abstract}

\end{@twocolumnfalse}]  

\section*{title}
\subsection*{title}
some tex here

\begin{table}[ht!]
\small
\caption{Concentrations d'ADN mesurées par spectrophotométrie et rapports d'absorbance A$_{260\;\unit{nm}}$/A$_{280\;\unit{nm}}$.}
\label{tab:absorbance}
\begin{tabularx}{7,9cm}{X p{1,8cm} X}
\hline 
\textbf{Extrait de la souche N°} & \textbf{[ADN]* en ng/$\mu$L}  & \textbf{Rapport d'absorbance A$_{260\;\unit{nm}}$/A$_{280\;\unit{nm}}$} \\  
\hline
1 & 1178,13 & 2,23 \\  
2 & 957,52 & 1,68 \\  
6 & 1470,09 & 2,18 \\  
7 & 983,12 & 2,11 \\  
11 & 1003,30 & 1,15 \\  
12 & 536,17 & 1,88 \\  
14 & 1163,83 & 2,10 \\  
17 & 201,00 & 1,84 \\  
18 & 552,17 & 2,15 \\  
19 & 890,13 & 2,26 \\  
20 & 588,75 & 2,07 \\  
22 & 307,13 & 1,83 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabularx} 
\caption*{\small\raggedright *[ADN] : Concentration d'ADN$_{\text{extrait}}$}
\end{table}

some text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Omit `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` (which I also very much doubt to not change the line spacing in `article`).

Comment: Without it it looks worse : http://i50.tinypic.com/2d9biq1.jpg

Comment: You need to add a minimal working example (i.e., one that a) is compilable b) shows the problem c) uses as few packages and custom macros as possible).

Comment: well it works with a different class. I just tried {scrartcl} to change the title of section style and now I have that new error

Comment: I recently installed TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012). I use TeXmaker 3.5.2 on Mountain Lion (Mac OS X 10.8.2). And the new error I was talking about is not really an error but it is the fact that I have disastrous spacing (see the picture: http://i50.tinypic.com/2d9biq1.jpg) when using the {scrartcl} class with my document and it is looking nice with the {article} class. I guess I will stick to the article class even though I cannot set the section's heading to be centered and in smallcaps because the "title sec" package is in conflict with something else.

Comment: @esmitex Try putting the command `\raggedbottom`just before `\begin{document}`. I also suggest using the `\typearea` -command built into KOMAscript to set the typing block. Remove the `\geometry`and put in the DIV8 or DIV9 or even DIV10 in the class options.

Comment: this solved the linespacing problem but without the geometry package all my margin settings changed and I have to resize all my figures and tables and how do I use the \typearea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `article` and `scrartcl` use the same rubber lengths before and after the section heading. So I think the most likely cause of the problem stems from the fact that those two classes have different default text width and text heights. The page break is occurring at a different place resulting in an underfull vbox. In order to compensate, TeX is stretching the vertical glue on the page and that's what's causing the extra gap. Try using the `geometry` package to adjust the text body. Example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[body={6.25in,8.25in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample Section}

\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Another section}

\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

In the above, if you remove the line loading the `geometry` package, the vertical spacing increases around the section headings.

Comment: I already use the following geometry package `\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}` (default settings given by Texmaker.

Comment: @esmitex If you have have `underfull vbox` messages in your log file, then extra gap is caused by the glue stretching. You could try `\raggedbottom` to prevent that.

Comment: I have a lot of `underfull hbox` and I use `\raggedbottom`

Comment: @esmitex: If you do not give us a MWE showing your problem we can only guess and that is no fun. Look in your actual work, search for a realy bad typesetted page and rebuild this page in your MWE. Include the minimim set of called packages to show the problem. Include `\raggedbottom` etc. what you have done to avoid the problem. If we have a MWE we can run it on our own computers and can talk with you about the same error messages or warnungs like: "in your code line x you have the warning because ..."

Comment: well it does not really affect the layout now, the code I had copied pasted in the question has been automatically changed

Comment: I have more stuff in the preamble maybe I forgot to add but I just gave up on that since the badbox are not affecting the layout so much and my paper is due for tomorrow morning.